mod rewrite for removing ? from the url
Am using apache2, I require to remove the question mark from my url. For example if my url http://192.168.20.120/docs/pay/?2023/04/text.pdf I need to remove ? and result http://192.168.20.120/docs/pay/2023/04/text.pdf

So you want to implement a redirection rule that matches requests to the path /docs/pay/ and captures the query string 2023/04/text.pdf, then appends it to the path and sends out the result as a redirection target to the requesting client. Sounds pretty straight forward. Assuming that you researched the topic and saw the hundreds of existing answers for such tasks here on SO ... what is the specific question you have? When implementing such a rule just the way shown in all those examples, what is the actual issue you ran into that made you ask here? Just so we can answer more specific?
